# Действие обратное .digest() python

Tags: python, хеширование

Есть байты в объекте hash к которому применили метод .digest()
Как обратно получить байты, чтобы использовать .hexdigest() и расшифровать байты в строку

```
import hashlib

hash = "89619fc70bfc7da0ede567e8e3266261d4c46b5fb35247dac53894b8875130cc"
nonce = 66

to_hash = (hash + str(nonce)).encode()
sha = hashlib.sha256(bytes(to_hash))
b = sha.digest())
```

Comment: В какой строку? Вы хеширование с шифрованием не перепутали?

Comment: @Эникейщик, не знаю перепутал не перепутал. Просто другой алгоритм выдает именно в таком формате. И изменить это не представляется возможным. Можно ли вообще обратить .digest()

Comment: Что вы хотите восстановить? sha? to_hash? hash?

Comment: @Эникейщик хеш который должен был получится в результате sha256 но реальные условия другие у меня есть только b из него нужно восстановить переменную sha а из неё по средству sha.hexdigest() будет хеш sha256

Comment: хеш-функции по определению необратимы, то что вы пытаетесь сделать - невозможно

Comment: hash 89619fc70bfc7da0ede567e8e3266261d4c46b5fb35247dac53894b8875130cc type sha256 result 3215246